# Translate into a sentence

Tags: cipher

> 111 221 241 151
>
> 222 543 421
>
> 233 161
>
> 166 222 331 353 444

The problem is to translate this into a sentence.

CLUES:

- `111`, could also be `166`, or `121`
- It is a Homophonic Substitution Cipher
- The code he gave me before this was:

  - `&!! "/ (?, }<€ \>!<* :~"& }?@!` translates to
  - `see if you can break this code`
- It is for an interview for an assistant trader position in Chicago.

Comment: Does each set of numbers represent a letter or a word?

Comment: I honestly don't know this numbers in that order and organized that way were all that was given to me

Comment: Maybe the sentence has 4 words, one per line. The numbers are referring to some text (maybe the book where you got this from?) where the first number is a page number, the second number is a line number, and the third is the number of the character on that line. ??

Comment: I see you've asked the same question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206570/translate-into-a-sentence

Comment: It can't be ASCII octal code with numbers as big as 543...

Comment: Is there any hint in *how* these numbers were given to you and by *whom* ? And potentially, *for what* - or rather *in what context* ?

Comment: @user224980 Can you pull out the Polybius Cipher parts into an answer? (And also, I personally think that the code you already solved should be removed since it's not related to the cipher you want us to crack)

Comment: @Len: clarification, the OQ _thinks_ it should be fairly elementary. If he referenced something well-known among traders but obscure to the rest of the world, we'll be sitting here with our thumb in for a long time.

That said, the idea that these might represent dice occurred to me almost immediately, but the most common three-die games don't match this pattern, nor are there really any tricks you can pull with cube-sides to turn it into letters without _some_ additional context.

Comment: oh, and one last thing: the OQ's prior use of symbols instead of letters in what is still a basic substitution cipher is the sort of over-clever thing I'd be looking for here, too. You could read it as two transforms if you wanted (one to substitute, one to turn it into symbols) -- OP just didn't have to figure out the second one that lives inside OQ's head. Might be something like that here, too.

Comment: IT ISN'T A POLYBIUS NOW I ASKED HIM

Comment: @lorimer check it out now

Comment: @Len: if he has taken this long to solve it (and come to the conclusion with an obviously immense amount of outside assistance) would you really still hire him for the job?

Comment: @IanMacDonald - Hmm.. How about if I just respond with a [comment](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13356/alphabet-number-matching#comment44100_13356) from Xnor  ;-)

Comment: @IanMacDonald I wouldn't say I got any outside help so far. I am not any closer to solving it then when I posted it. I would say this last idea i posted has to be the path to the solution there is not much else left

Comment: What city are you interviewing in?

Comment: @user224980 if you think you're going to solve this by brute force, you're going to have a bad time. In a small (~6000 words) dictionary of most common words, after eliminating words that have a duplicate letter, there would be about 253,000,000 potential combinations of the correct lengths. Of those, about 68,000 combinations (272,000 words) have their only duplicate letters in the correct places. For reference, that word count would be somewhere between Paradise Lost and Ulysses in length, but full of nonsense like "mild use to punch" or "tidy cow be scrap." Good luck not going crazy.

Comment: chicago and i was just given a clue check it now

Comment: @len we have a clue now check it out

Comment: @user224980 - I don't see any math reason why 111, 166, 121 are all the same. It is still quite possible that these numbers point to words or letters in a list of codes (like a list of securities or inputs or rules). Were there any lists that you were required to learn?

Comment: @len nope. It's going to translate to a cleaver sentence like the last.

Comment: @len where does 121 come from is my problem right now?

Comment: not necessarily. even though it is very short for frequency analysis we might be able to start with 222 being e or something like that

Comment: @user224980 - Frequency analysis makes no sense for a homophonic substitution cipher!

Answer (score 6):

- Although this code looks similar to a Polybius cipher, I don't think it is one. Groups of **3 digits** would use a 3x3x3 grid and the numbers would be from 1 to 3.  Numbers from 1 to 6 would use a 6x6 grid with groups of **2 digits**. If a 6x6x6 grid was used, it would be impossible to decode.
- It is notable that the code contains a majority of 1's and 2's with no 0's, 7's, 8's, or 9's. Perhaps the code is based on a system of 3 digit numbers from the "real world" like bus routes or office numbers or pages of a training manual.
- As you suggest, we could try finding 4 words that fit the ABCD EFG HI JEKLM pattern. An example is **"john was by twice"** but it seems quite difficult to make a sensible sentence.

---

- As noted by JLee, this code resembles a **[book cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_cipher)** but the name of a book (or some written document) is required to decode.

---

- Several 3 digit codes are in common use including the US ZIP code prefixes and the Dewey Decimal system (North American area codes do not use 100 series numbers). The following table shows the meaning of each 3 digit code, however this does not help with decoding the cipher.

[image: 3digitcodes]

Comment: That is the exact thing I got, with mod 26, but I saw the gibberish and thought I was barking up the wrong tree. Thanks for the quipquip link. I didn't know about it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to do mod-26 + 1, since the alphabet is not zero-indexed? We're getting a range of [0,25] here. I don't know if that changes what gets output by quipquip.

Comment: i dont quite understand how to apply mode-26 how could 111 and 241 both represent the same letter?

Comment: the last one i was sent translated to "see if you can break this code" it might be something clever like that

Comment: i dont see how it could be a book cipher though if this was all that i was given with no mention of any books

Comment: wouldn't u think that each set would be one word I think we are on the right track here but dont have the right letters down

Comment: wouldn't the code make more sense if each grouping of numbers made a word? sorry im new to these

Comment: @Len i definitely think we are very close now. the phrase or sentence will make sense i am almost positive of that so we should know when we get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22311/discussion-between-user224980-and-len).

Comment: how do i put it in the featured list? there is no more context to the question that's the problem. I got sent this and was told to make a sentence out of it.

Comment: the code he gave me before this was &!!  "/  (?,  }<€  \>!<*  :~"&  }?@! it translates to "see if you can break this code" it was for an interview for an assistant trader position

Comment: @Len i updated it

Comment: @len "john was by twice" can't be the answer because ever letter has to be different except the 1st of the 2nd word and 2nd letter of the fourth word. that's my theory right now

Comment: @user224980 - Check more closely. Every letter **is** different except for 2 w's. I know it is not the answer, it is just an example. It will be difficult if not impossible to come up with a sensible sentence like the previous answer.

Comment: @JLee *quipqiup

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```
THIS   111 221 241 151  
ONE    222 543 421  
IS     233 161  
TOUGH  166 222 331 353 444
```

User224980 explanation (from comment) - What it ended up coming down to was a lot of guess and check. Obviously the letters were represented by more than one number. Like I said before, you were going to know if you got the answer. Another clever one!

Len's summary of other comments below - This answer does seem most appropriate but it is disappointing because there should still be an explanation for associating the numbers in the question with the letters in the answer.

Comment: tough to explain. really what it ended up coming down to was a lot of guess and check. obviously the letters were represented by more than one number. Like I said a thousand times before you were going to know if you got the answer. Another cleaver one! I can go into greater detail if need be

Comment: Please do go into greater detail.

Comment: @user224980 "if need be" - yes, this is PSE so if you're posting an answer, it needs detail :-)

Comment: If the solution was just trial and error, I don't think anything's really been solved -- we need more detail on how you got from 'a' to 'b'. While there is only one repeated 'character' in the ciphertext, there are 5 different repeated ones in the plaintext. In fact, there are only _four_ letters in the plaintext that _aren't_ duplicated, E G N U; all of H I S T O are repeated once.

Comment: 1) Was this 4-word sentence really long enough to allow the cipher to be solved? . 2) Was this a "guess what I am thinking" type of puzzle? . 3) Are you and your friend the same person? . 4) "Clever" means "mentally bright" but "cleaver" means "a heavy, broad-bladed knife"

Comment: How do you know it's this and not "THAT ONE IS TOUGH" instead? Or for that matter, "THIS ONE IS TOAST," "SMUG MAN IS SMART," or "STEP TWO IS STUDY?" But let's assume you're right, because it does make sense. If you were handed another ciphertext encoded in the same way, with the same key, would you be able to find it any faster? If not, you haven't solved it at all. Is this guy supposed to be impressed at your guessing skills? I'd be pretty disappointed if someone solved my interview puzzle and then told me they basically just guessed, especially if it took them over a month to do it.

Comment: I had guessed this exact answer a few days ago. I couldn't figure out how to actually reason it out, so I didn't bother posting an answer.

Comment: Umm...unless PSE is messing up, both the question and the answer were supplied by user224980 and edited by @len. Did this person just give themself a +150 bounty?

Comment: @tfitzger - Yes, the Q and A were originated by user224980.  But I put up the bounty to help get an answer (you can see this in the edit history of the question).  So even though the answer was disappointing, I gave the bounty to user224980.

Comment: @Len gotcha. I was slightly confused.

 It would be interesting to try and figure out the methodology behind how the homophones were chosen, if there was a methodology. Why, for example, is `I` represented by both `151` and `161`, and what are the other cipher keys...

Comment: @tfitzger - I would also like to know. I think it is like the [Beale ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beale_ciphers) where the numbers referenced words in the Declaration of Independence. But we don't know what document to use for this cipher.

Comment: you are all over thinking it the dude made it up off the top of his head. there is no document it corresponds to.

Comment: @user224980 So for an interview question the solution was to randomly plug in letters for a homophonic substitution cipher? That's completely absurd. The numbers may as well have been hieroglyphics, making the 1-6 range and three digits meaningless. If somehow that actually was an interview question and that was how you were supposed to solve it, I'd run away. Fast.