# Alphabet Number Matching

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence

If :

```
888888 = T 

777777 = O

555555 = Y

444444 = R
```

then :

```
666666 = ?
```

Basically you need to tell the logic along with the solution to the puzzle.

Comment: Is there a value for each letter? Or just 5 letters?

Comment: @Daedric : Only 6 numbers are given with respect to each alphabet.

Comment: I mean theoretically would there be a number for each letter? Like is it a pattern that could be applied to each letter in the alphabet to get a unique number? I don't really understand your response.

Comment: @Daedric : I myself am not sure about it since this question was asked  during some online test .

Comment: Do you know the answer of this problem?

Comment: @leoll2 : Yeah but don't know the logic behind it.

Comment: Can you post the exact wording of the original question?

Comment: @MarkBannister : That is the exact wording. They have given 4 equations and asked to find the answer of the 5th one.

Comment: If you don't know the logic can you be sure there is logic behind it? Is this a reputable site?

Comment: @Daedric : One can't be sure of the logic behind the question until we know the logic . It was asked as a part of online round of an algorithmic trading company .

Comment: I really wanted the solution to have something to do with Toys R Us :(

Comment: @TusharMakkar Word of advice: a trading company that usesa complete-the-pattern brainteaser to judge interview candidates is [probably not a good place to work for](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/36583).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the answer is

> X

Explanation

> 8 X 6 = FORTY EIGH(T)
>  7 X 6 = FOURTY TW(O)
>  5 X 6 = THIRT(Y)
>  4 X 6 = TWENTY FOU(R)
>  6 X 6 = THIRTY SI(X)