# Convert to a sentence

Tags: cipher

Here is a sequence of numbers, convert to a sentence.

123 436 200

142 166

341 401 304 216 255

143 304 303

211 320 303 303 214 336

Note: There is a logical and basic answer to this.

---

**Modifications:**

Hint 1:

> The answer has nothing to do with logarithms.

Hint 2:

> This puzzle could be solved with just a pencil and paper. No external references are needed.

Hint 3:

> This puzzle uses a Homophonic Substitution Cipher

Comment: One two three, four three six, two O O...

Comment: @Alex you know what I mean

Comment: hah give me some times on it!

Comment: Are these two similar or is it just me?  http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10991/translate-into-a-sentence

Comment: @Akiiino I felt rather disappointed after spending a long time attempting that one (and seeing the likes/faves/bounty for an unfulfilling answer) so I made this puzzle for closure.

Comment: Can we get a hint? Do we need a hint?

Comment: @JLee here's somewhat of a hint: the answer has nothing to do with logarithms. A hint definitely isn't needed to solve this though.

Comment: I added a hint section. The section isn't really needed though, the puzzle alone has certain features that draw you to certain ideas. (Don't read into this, this isn't a hint just a general statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NOT AS TOUGH BUT BETTER
>
> These are base 7 numbers. Convert them to decimal and then use mod 26 for a straight alphabetic substitution cipher.

Comment: Ugh. Literally the first thing I tried was this but with base 6 instead. Should've tried more than a couple letters and I'd have realized it was the wrong one... Well done!

Comment: Nice, that's the answer I was looking for. Since the numbers range from 0 to  6 you'd naturally think they were base 7 numbers, and from there, there's basically one main way to convert to letters. 

Hint 1 referred to "logical and basic", the basic part referred to the base change. Also, I had "Modifications" in bold to hint using mod 26 for the letter conversion. I definitely went overboard with the hints :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> BUT IS THERE ANY ANSWER

Strategy used:

> The 2-5-3 word lengths in the middle of the sentence clearly pointed to "is there any" and the rest was filled in based on OP's reported frustration with a different problem on Puzzling.SE.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to need more convincing. Your letters duplicate when none of the numbers in the OP duplicate, and the answer could just as well be DIE BY THEIR OLD PUZZLE, etc. I don't like the idea of guessing just based on the word lengths.

Comment: This can't be right. There are two sets of duplicate numbers in the puzzle. The first (341) and third (304) letters of the third word should match the third letter of the last word (341) and the 2nd letter of the 4th word (304), respectively, at minimum. In your solution, 341 would need to be both T and S, and 304 would be both E and N.

Comment: Sorry that's not the answer. Try to use my hint (I'll edit my post to make it clear it's a hint).